# GOlang | Proxy an HTTPS request to another proxy without hijacking

Tags: go, networking, https, proxy

i have got a few proxy like so

```
http://user:pass@192.168.1.3:3333
http://user:pass@192.168.1.4:3333
http://user:pass@192.168.1.5:3333
...
```

I'm trying to program a proxy in GO, which receives a request, check user:pass, in case the request is valid it executes the request with one of the proxies I have in my list and then stream the response to the user
saving the response size to monitor the usage of a single user.
At the moment i managed to implement http and socks5, everything works as requested.
the problem arises with https, i read that the two ways to handle a https proxy are:

1. hijack the request and then man in the middle (causing problems with certificates)
2. create a tunnel with the CONNECT method
   I managed to implement the connect method, but the tunnel is done with my machine and not one of the proxy servers in the list.

I tried the goproxy package, but it doesn't fit my needs because the only way to access url/body/method is by hijacking the request, and i can't do it.

I tried to open a second tunnel once i received the request with the following code

```go
func handleClient(clientConn net.Conn) {
    defer clientConn.Close()

    // Read the CONNECT request from the client
    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    n, err := clientConn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading client request:", err)
        return
    }

    // Parse the CONNECT request to get the destination address
    connectRequest := string(buf[:n])
    targetHost := strings.Split(strings.Split(connectRequest, " ")[1], ":")[0]
    targetPort := "80" // Default port for HTTP

    // Connect to the proxy server
    proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://192.168.1.4:3333")
    proxyConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", proxyURL.Host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to proxy:", err)
        return
    }
    defer proxyConn.Close()

    // Prepare the CONNECT request with Proxy-Authorization header
    authHeader := "Basic " + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("test:testpassword"))
    connectRequest = fmt.Sprintf("CONNECT %s:%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s:%s\r\nProxy-Authorization: %s\r\n\r\n", targetHost, targetPort, targetHost, targetPort, authHeader)

    // Send the CONNECT request to the proxy
    proxyConn.Write([]byte(connectRequest))

    // Read the response from the proxy (HTTP status line)
    proxyResponse := make([]byte, 4096)
    _, err = proxyConn.Read(proxyResponse)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading proxy response:", err)
        return
    }

    // Send the proxy's response back to the client
    clientConn.Write(proxyResponse)

    // Forward data between client and proxy
    go func() {
        _, _ = io.Copy(clientConn, proxyConn)
    }()

    _, _ = io.Copy(proxyConn, clientConn)
}
```

but curl response is

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8888 https://www.google.com -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8888...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.google.com:443
> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* CONNECT phase completed
* CONNECT tunnel established, response 200
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308)
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with www.google.com port 443
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308)
```

My question at the moment is: is double tunnel with CONNECT wrong? is there actually a method to do what I would like (like a proxychain)? if so how?